# What is the Johnson family of distributions good for? What are their main features and applications?

Tags: distributions, probability, reliability, project-management

I saw the Johnson family of distributions in context of reliability and demand modeling for supply chains, but I am not sure if they are bringing real benefit to pay for their relatively more complex format. What are their major features and when one should use them?